# Do not show location service icon in status bar but still use background updates

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios8, cllocationmanager

I'm looking for some solution to handle the problem: 
If I use `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` there're appears an location icon in status bar and never disappears, so, it is the problem - user can think that my app drain battery, but it's not.

So, when I use `.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` I can't call `didUpdateLocations` function to update location even I add fetch background update, the #selector does not allow to call that method.

I want my app get location updates in background without always showing the location icon in the status bar. How can I update location by fetch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, when I use .requestWhenInUseAuthorization() I can't call didUpdateLocations function

Yes you can. If you go into the background when you are updating locations, you can continue to update locations. What you cannot do is *start* updating locations *from the background*.

> I want my app get location updates in background

Use deferred location updates or location monitoring. This will keep your use of sensors to the minimum. Otherwise, the user's impression that you are using up the battery while in the background is entirely justified.

Comment: "location monitoring" uses regions which works only with .requestAlwaysAuthorization()

Comment: But no location icon appears in the status bar associated with your app, and that is the question you asked.